# How to UV unwrap MULTIPLE image textures on top of one another?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I have a package label with a background illustration that I'm trying to emboss so I decided UV unwrapping the label design into separate layers and onto the bottle "panel" would be the best option only problem is up until right now I only know how to uvwrap ONE image onto ONE surface at a time.

I've tried creating a new UV map in the data panel and adding the second image texture to it's material but that hasn't worked.

[image]

The top left image is the first image text and the bottom right is the one I'm trying to unwrap on top of it.

Comment: add an uv node and select the uv which you want to use and after you can combine them with mix rgb node being the factor input the alpha of the image that is going over

Comment: To add a transparent image on top of a material [read this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853)

Comment: To use multiple materials on an object [read this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: To search for similar posts use the search box at the top.